# getting property value in powershell when running convertto-html

Tags: powershell

I'm still new to powershell, and recently i came to know about get-member properties. However when i pipe the command to convertto-html the value disappear.

i have a data which is called link.csv and below is the content of the file

```
    Target      Node  Address          Status
------      ----  -------          ------
server01 0:2:3 20230002AC0153AF Up    
server01 0:2:4 20240002AC0153AF Up    
server01 1:2:3 21230002AC0153AF Up    
server01 1:2:4 21240002AC0153AF Up
```

I'm able to get the property value as per below.

```
PS C:\Report\script\Temp> $a= Import-Csv .\link.csv | select Target,Node,Address,Status 

PS C:\Report\script\Temp> $a.Node[1]
0:2:4

PS C:\Report\script\Temp> $a.Status[1]
Up

PS C:\Report\script\Temp> $a.Target[1]
server01
```

However when i output it to Convertto-Html

```
PS C:\Report\script\Temp> $a= Import-Csv .\link.csv | select Target,Node,Address,Status | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -PreContent "<font color=`"Black`"><H4>Remote Copy Group - $b</H4></font> "

PS C:\Report\script\Temp> $a.Target[1]
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:1 char:1
+ $a.Target[1]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

How can i get the property value while running convertto-html command.
Hope you can help me with the issue.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: the `.Target` property _does not exist_ in the HTML fragment. it's been converted to HTML. what do you want to get from `$a.Target[1]`?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey i want to be able to get the value as i'm going to set a the column colour base on the status property.

Comment: then save the data to $Var1 and use that to generate the HTML ... and save that into $Var2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to capture *intermediate results* in the pipeline, use the `-OutVariable` / `-ov` [common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters) with a *variable name* in order to store these results in that variable:

```
$html = Import-Csv .\link.csv |
  Select-Object Target, Node, Address, Status -OutVariable a | 
    ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -PreContent "<font color=`"Black`"><H4>Remote Copy Group - $b</H4></font> "

$a.Target[1]
```

Note how the pipeline overall returns *HTML* (as an array of lines), whereas the intermediate custom objects filtered from the CSV input are stored in variable `$a` via `-OutVariable`, for later use - note how you must pass just the variable *name* to `-OutVariable`, without the `$` sigil, i.e., just `a` rather than `$a`.